# Changing color for text and icon in same table cell

Tags: javascript, php

I know how to set a different color for each text value.

First, I'm checking and setting $driverStatus as a string:

```
if ($log->field_is_online_value == 'online') {
    $driverStatus = 'Online';
} elseif ($log->field_is_online_value == 'offline') {
    $driverStatus = 'Offline';
} else {
    $driverStatus = 'Busy';
}
```

Then forming the table and pasting the string from PHP:

```
<table id="locations">
    <tr><th>Driver status</th></tr>
    <tr><td>'.$driverStatus.'</td></tr>
</table>
```

And finally checking text and changing the color respectively:

```
var cells = document.getElementById("locations").getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML == "Online") {
        cells[i].style.color = "#5CB85C";
    } else if (cells[i].innerHTML == "Offline") {
        cells[i].style.color = "#D9534F";
    } else if (cells[i].innerHTML == "Busy") {
        cells[i].style.color = "#F0AD4E";
    }
}
```

I need to set the same color for both text and icon if string looks like this:

```
$driverStatus = 'Online&nbsp&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>';
$driverStatus = 'Offline&nbsp&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i>';
$driverStatus = 'Busy&nbsp&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>';
```

Comment: You should do by adding different classes to that "location" element. Also, don't use tables for layout, it's not 1997 anymore.

Comment: can't you define a 2nd var ? ie: `$driverStatus = 'Online'; $driverDisplay = 'Online <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>'` then just print the latter ? Plus: according to status, use CSS to style the row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$driverStatus = 'Online&nbsp&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>';
//...

var cells = document.getElementById("locations").getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    var icon = cell.getElementsByTagName("i")[0];

    if (cell.innerHTML == 'Online&nbsp&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>') {
        cell.style.color = "#5CB85C";
        icon.style.color = "#5CB85C";
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```